# Check if custom Font exists in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In UIKit I was able to access a custom font like this

```swift
guard let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 12) else {
   fatalError("Font not available")
}
```

In SwiftUI we get a custom font like this.

```swift
//Swift UI Version
let font = Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 12)
```

The issue seems to be that if you have not "registered" the font in the UIKit version you would get the fatal error. Which is fine as you could just register the font at that point if needed.

The SwiftUI version seems to just return the system SF font if the font is not registered.

I would like to know a way to check if a font has been registered before I access it view SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2):

UIFont exists in SwiftUI as well. Check the value, and set a `@State` value based on the result. `Font` has a completely different use; it's always is going to resolve to something. UIFont didn't go away with the release of SwiftUI (nor did CoreText or a many other tools).

Comment: I looked through documentation and could not find a way to use a UIFont in SwiftUI. I think I understand what you mean though. Use the UIFont constructor to do the "check" and then return the Font if the check passes.

Comment: Exactly. There's no "UIFont in SwiftUI" any more than there's "String in SwiftUI" or "CBPeripheral in SwiftUI." All the tools are still available. SwiftUI doesn't eliminate UIKit any more than Foundation eliminates CoreFoundation. For now and for a very long time to come, SwiftUI is built on top of UIKit.